# Is saying "I'm people" in a certain context correct?

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality-in-context

After reading my previous post carefully, I could say that this question is different from this question: [Is "It's people" grammatically correct?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322217/is-its-people-grammatically-correct/322294#322294).

Suppose, there is this monolog:

> There are times when I loathe people. Mind you, I'm people.

I mean to write a trait of hatred aimed at a group of "people" and I belong to that "group" as well. I hope that makes sense.

Is it at least natural or perhaps can be grammatical if we treat "people" as a noun. Do I have to add an indefinite article then? I did try to search "I'm people" on Google and I found there's a song called "I'm a people". However, I don't know whether it has a same meaning as mine or not. Also I need to know whether the sentence —our topic above— is correct. If it is, correct in a sense of natural sounding or grammatical or else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only makes sense in a jocular "bad English" way. It sounds a little ridiculous, so it might be funny enough to be used as a "funny" expression. But if a learner of English used such an expression it would be assumed to just be a mistake.

Instead, "I'm a person" would be the un-funny way to express this idea.

Comment: "I'm one of these people."